# Is it possible to dynamically load Go code?

Tags: go

As the title says I want to dynamically load a Go package (or not) based on information only available at run time.

The objective is to allow the user to extend the program via custom packages that add new native script commands. Currently every time I add new commands or want to disallow some commands, I need to edit the program and recompile, whereas if I could make some kind of dll or the like then I could create a "import" script command to search for and load a named command library.

For the curious the program in question is custom command based scripting library that I use for all kinds of things.

I did some searching ahead of time, and the results don't look good, but I could not find a clear no.

Comment: this would be a bad idea. You don't want to create di of entire packages just for comfort

Comment: It's not just for comfort, it's to allow me to extend offer optional extensions for those who want them without having to give thm to everyone.

Comment: I hats stack overflow for guys who are sayng "you don't need this" just give answer if you have one. And then suggest other way. Many times, even if author actually needs something different, many guys are getting to this question from search, needing exactly that.

Comment: Is there a way to load .so of other languages dynamically at run-time? CGO only allows loading specific .so at the start of the program (and not choose at runtime).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load package dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641296/load-package-dynamically)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go does not support dynamic libraries yet. Elias Naur has recently published some patches, but they have not been reviewed yet and it is unlikely that they will be included in Go 1.2. You can read the discussions on Google Groups:

- https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/o0VTTqC8hOU/discussion
- https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/P05BDjLcQ5k/discussion

As far as I know, that are the most recent discussions about that topic.

There is however another approach. You can start your plugins in separate processes and use the [net/rpc](http://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/) package to communicate with your main app. This also allows you to dynamically start / stop / recompile separate plugins and it has the advantage that a bad plugin can not crash your program. Go excels at network communication, you just have to make good use of it.

> I need to edit the program and recompile,

You can also consider writing a small script that watches for changes in the current directory (using fsnotify) and executes "go build" followed by a restart of your program. I use this approach on some of my web projects during local development and it works fine. I am not able to observe any compilation times and I am quite fast at switching and refreshing my browser window. My Python development cycle, where the interpreter has to be restarted and all modules have to be reimported on every change (and that might take a significant time in larger projects!), feels really clumsy in comparison to Go.

Comment: Thanks, I knew DLLs are not supported but I was currious if any one new a way to fake some thing like them. Looks like RPC is the way to go, dynamic recompilation won't work for a library.

Comment: After some testing, it looks like rpc will not work for what I need :( It looks like a plugin system using all go code is imposible as it stands.

Comment: One year later: Have things evolved on that front? Like Milo, I'm trying to create a plugin system in pure go:-/

Comment: I know the go 1.5 would support generating dynamic libraries, but I'm not sure it would support dynamic load then. Anyone knows?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641296/load-package-dynamically-in-golang

Answer (score 4):

There's support for this in Go 1.8. It's pretty immature and rudimentary at the moment, but it's finally possible.

Also Mateusz Gajewski's [go-bind-plugin](https://github.com/wendigo/go-bind-plugin) project may be of interest, as it simplifies using loaded plugins.

From the [plugin package](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/) documentation:

For example, a plugin defined as

```
package main

// // No C code needed.
import "C"

import "fmt"

var V int

func F() { fmt.Printf("Hello, number %d\n", V) }
```

may be loaded with the Open function and then the exported package symbols V and F can be accessed

```
p, err := plugin.Open("plugin_name.so")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
v, err := p.Lookup("V")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
f, err := p.Lookup("F")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
*v.(*int) = 7
f.(func())() // prints "Hello, number 7"
type Symbol interface{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a [dlopen-package for Go](https://godoc.org/github.com/cookieo9/goffi/dlopen) -- so, at least, you can load your shared library (DLL) into your Go-program now... You'll, probably, have to code your extension in C, C++ or something else, for which you have tools capable of generating shared libraries.