# Load package dynamically

Tags: dynamic, go, load, runtime, package

Is it possible to load a specific package during runtime? 
I want to have a kind of plugins where each one has the same functions than the others but with different behaviour, and depending on the configuration file, load one or other.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You might consider executing the ‘plugin’ packages at runtime, by writing out a new program (say, to a temp directory) and executing via [exec.Command](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/), something along the lines of `exec.Command("go", "run", files…).Run()`

You’ll see some similar code [here](https://github.com/clipperhouse/gen/blob/master/execute.go).

Comment: Hi, thank you, it could solve my problem, and I could communicate both with zeroMQ or similar.

Comment: I make "dynamic loading" by build several plugins independently, these plugins must support reading data from stdin, then in the main.go, I read plugin list from a config file, then use exec.Command to start each plugin (in go routine), then I can write to plugins' StdinPipe, and each plugin can read.

Answer (score 40):

No, Go doesn't support dynamically loaded libraries.

Your best bet is to start the plugin as its own executable and communicate with it through sockets or via stdin/stdout.

*2017 update*

This answer is no longer true, Go now supports [plugins](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/) (for Linux and MacOS only as of June 2021)

Comment: But in that way, how can I load the package for the first time without knowing which package would be used?

Comment: But still only on Linux (as of go 1.8)

Comment: Well, linux and osx.

Comment: It's not stable yet! `The plugin support is currently incomplete, only supports Linux, and has known bugs. Please report any issues.`

Answer (score 27):

There is support for this now as of go 1.8

https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Just do these,create a codegen that reads the configuration, generates a basic go file with the packages loaded in order  and then execute that, compile languages won't nor provide dynamic loading, even dart suffers in a way,simple just read your configuration file then create a temporary file with the necessary codes to load up and communicate with sockets  or http

Comment: "compile languages won't nor provide dynamic loading" - c/c++ are compiled languages and they do provide it through 'dlopen'. Virtually all languages provide some sort of dynamic loading except for go.

Comment: And now there is a [dlopen-package for Go](https://godoc.org/github.com/cookieo9/goffi/dlopen), which allows use of shared libraries. How you generate those -- and whether you can turn Go-code into a _library_ -- are separate concerns...

Answer (score -5):

I think what you are looking for is the special function `init`

if you add a

```
func init() {

}
```

inside a package it will run it the first time the package is imported.
This happens only in the same binary. As other have already said go does not support dynamically loaded libraries.

Comment: The problem with init is that I don't know which package should be loaded until the config file is read. So if I can't load a package dynamically, the init way is not the solution.