# Create system to dynamicly load and unload shared objects as plugins

Tags: go, inheritance, plugins, .so

I want to learn is how to make a main application be able to load extensions or plugins to enhance the functionality of said app. based on my knowledge of other languages, here's what I imagined it would look like.

1. first is to have an interface in the application which all plugin to-be loaded into the app will be derived from:

```golang
// some_package_in_the_main_app.go

type Plugin interface {

  // function is called when the app starts
  Enable()

  // function is called when the app stops
  Disable()
}
```

2. next is to make a plugin to add functionality to the app:

```golang
// some_plugin_package.go

func (*Plugin) Enable() {
}

func (*Plugin) Disable() {
}
```

I want to know how to hook it all up in an easy to manage system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load package dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641296/load-package-dynamically)

Comment: Go has plugin support: https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/

Comment: Note that Go plugins can only be loaded but not unloaded, and currently they are not supported on Windows (may change in the future).

Comment: This question needs to be edited, it's too broad. Everything is depends on what you want to achieve, what is the content of the plugin. I just can give suggestion on 'function is called when the app starts/stops'. If you want to call function if app stops by trapping `os.Exit`, you can't, period. But if the app has condition to stop, you can use `defer`. On contrary, you can use `init` on package `main` when app starts.

Comment: New to Go and directly diving into one of the most complicated things might not be the best idea.