# Adding a new implementation without having to touch an existing code - how?

Tags: go, design-patterns, architecture

There're 2 entities in a Go program: country states and years. A program calculates some data by receiving input from a user.
The list of country states is constant, whereas years, as the time goes on, of course not.

I want to structure my program in such a way that it'll be flexible from the point of view of adding new year without changing the existing code.
How would I do it? I need an architecture pattern for such a case, that is.

I want to avoid something like this:

```
func CalculateData(cs, year) -> ReturnDataStructure {
    if year == 2000 {
        return calculateDataFor2000(cs)
    } else if year == 2001 {
        return calculateDataFor2001(cs)
    } else if year == 2002 {
        return calculateDataFor2002(cs)
    } else //and so on


    // as years go by, add a new year...
    } else if year == 2052 {
        return calculateDataFor2052(cs)
    }

    //....
}
```

Instead I want to be able to **add** only: I'd add an implementation, perhaps in a separate file, without having to touch the existing code, as the years go by.
That is, the function `CalculateData(...)` should become this flexible, or extensible, for it work properly and it shouldn't know how many years there are. The years must not be hard-coded.

Each new implementation must be compiled **statically**.

How would one do it?

Comment: @mkopriva would that touch existing code? Yes - it wouldn't satisfy my requirement. No - it would. Easy

Comment: `calculateDataForXXX()` has dependencies on the year. The dependencies must be put into files, whatever those dependencies be (numbers, rules etc). Your app must parse these files, and use them. Without further info we can't give better answer.

Comment: @icza what kind of futher info do you ask about?

Comment: Like an example what `calculateDataFor2000()` looks like. If your code is long, come up with a [mcve].

Comment: @mkopriva why you say mistake? That's what I ask about.

Comment: @icza "return 2000 * 123" is what it looks like

Comment: @icza `The dependencies must be put into files, whatever those dependencies be (numbers, rules etc). Your app must parse these files, and use them. ` --> this won't work for me

Comment: @Ojag If all your calculations are just a simple multiplication, then the multiplier should be stored in files. If not, again, come up with a [mcve].

Comment: @mkopriva post your answer if you think that there's no problem with it

Comment: @icza what if in reality my calculations aren't  simple, but  complex multiplications?

Comment: @Ojag Then you either can't have what you want, or you have to abstract those calculations somehow and define rules that drive them, rules which you can store and parse from files.

Comment: @icza doesn't there exist a special design pattern for my goal? But not in a way you describe it, not by loading them from files and parsing them, but more statically.

Comment: @mkopriva correct

Comment: @Ojag You want your code to _change_ without actually _changing_ it. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: You could use plugins and load them at runtime. That still requires writing code, just not touching the original code base. Loading plugins also works without restarting the app though.

Comment: @icza Should be possible. I want an appropriate implementation to get executed without changing the main code. The same way one would implement an interface for a newly added struct.

Comment: @mkopriva they differ a lot. Everying changes or can change. The code will handle any year

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write Go code to do the calculations, it seems you're stuck with compiling it in.  There's no Go equivalent to the opening of a shared object file. See [Load package dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641296/load-package-dynamically).

If I understand your question, your problem is that you don't know exactly what math will need to be performed for each year, so you don't want to hard code the math into your application. You don't need a dynamic library to do that.  You can either build your own expression evaluator (see "The Go Programming Language" 7.9), or use an embeddable language  such as Lua (https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Shopify/go-lua).  Either way, you can move the math "out" of the Go code and associate it with its year in a file.  Each year you can write the math for that year, and then the Go won't have to change.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a package level variable of type `map[string]func(...)` so that for each year you can set an handler.

If you need to organize those functions into separate packages, you can consider adding a public Register function and let them register the handler at initialization during runtime execution.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}

var computeYears = map[string]func(cs string) interface{}{
    "2000": calculateDataFor2000,
    "2001": calculateDataFor2001,
    "2002": func(cs string) interface{} { return nil },
}

func CalculateData(cs, year string) interface{} {
    x, ok := computeYears["year"]
    if ok {
        return x(cs)
    }
    /*
       if year == 2000 {
           return calculateDataFor2000(cs)
       } else if year == 2001 {
           return calculateDataFor2001(cs)
       } else if year == 2002 {
           return calculateDataFor2002(cs)
       } else //and so on


       // as years go by, add a new year...
       } else if year == 2052 {
           return calculateDataFor2052(cs)
       }
    */
    panic("no such implmentation for the year " + year)
    return nil
}

func calculateDataFor2000(cs string) interface{} {
    return nil
}

func calculateDataFor2001(cs string) interface{} {
    return nil
}

// In the case you need to delcare thse function in separate packages,
// use a public function t let them regser at init time.
func Register(year string, handler func(cs string) interface{}) {
    computeYears[year] = handler
}

func init() {
    fmt.Println("init time")
    Register("2003", calculateDataFor2000)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/zI8GCCPj1ew