# How to send client request to gRPC server during runtime based on provided proto

Tags: go, grpc-go

From official website [Go gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/), we can generate gRPC code using `protoc` with a `.proto` file. And then we can setup server and send gRPC request.

But now I want to send gRPC request to an any gRPC server with a specified '.proto' file. So I should parse the `.proto` file and then send gRPC request to that gRPC server.

Could any one know how to realize it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to generate a client anyways. The beauty of grpc is static typing. I found [this](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jhump/protoreflect/dynamic/grpcdynamic) library, not sure if it is what you are looking for. I don't think that go supports dynamic libraries yet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237863/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-load-go-code), so I'm not sure how easy this is to implement.